# Is there a way to add a padding before an inline element that is ignored if the element is on a new line?

Tags: html, css

I am working on styling a link that I would like to display inline following a brief `<p>` element. Ideally, I'd like that link to appear inline with the text but with a small space between the link and the end of the paragraph. It looks exactly how I want it when the paragraph text ends in the middle of the line and the link comes directly after. The problem is that I want to keep the link text ("Learn More") together and not break across lines, so when the whole element ends up on a new line, it has the padding before it as well.

This is a Squarespace site, so some of the default CSS styling is a little opaque and you have to re-style any stuff in code blocks, especially links. I've tried using `inline` and `inline-block` display types.

EDIT: Here's the code block with the text:

```html
<h2 style=text-align:center;>
  Headline Text
</h2>
<p class="issue-explain">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a class="issue-learn" href="/test">Learn More →</a></p>
```

Here is what I've currently got in CSS.

```css
a.issue-learn {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

Here's what it looks like when the text isn't long enough to force the link to another line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KenRH.png

And here's what it looks like when the text pushes the link down to the next line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/07X0n.png

Comment: If you'd be able to give us the whole code, that would help us troubleshooting this a bunch. In the meantime, check if your link is inside the text DIV or if theres some kind of <br> between the link and the text DIV.

Comment: Sure thing. I just updated the original post with the HTML with the text. There's no <br> in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
/*SO related*/
body{max-width:290px;}

p.issue-explain{
display:inline;
}

p.issue-explain::after{
content:" ";
margin-left:1em;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center;">
  Headline Text
</h2>
<p class="issue-explain">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. aaaaaaa</p>

<a class="issue-learn" href="/test">Learn More →</a>

<h2 style="text-align:center;">
  Second article
</h2>
<p class="issue-explain">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. consequat. consequat.</p>

<a class="issue-learn" href="/test">Learn More →</a>
```

Comment: That's the ticket. Gotta love ```::after```. Thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

`word-break: keep-all;`

Comment: I just did. It doesn't seem to resolve the issue of the padding. I want to keep the whole link element text together (Learn More →), not break it at a particular spot.